# How to get the sent message when a command is executed Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If a user in a discord channel sends:

```
v!test Hello
```

How could I get the console to print

```
User#1321: Hello
```

I'm not sure how I can achieve this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
import discord # using discord.py

client = discord.Client() # creating a client instance

@client.event # decorator to register function in the client events
async def on_message(message): # this function gets called every time the client receives a message
    split_message = message.content.split(' ') # split the message into parts
    prefix = split_message[0]
    if prefix != 'v!test': # if the prefix doesn't match, we stop
        return
    rest = ' '.join(split_message[0:]) # this is everything except your v!test prefix
    print(f'{str(message.author)}: {rest}')

client.run('your_token')
```